# Laravel Spark Dynamic Developers (for Kiosk)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-spark

The [Spark Documentation](https://spark.laravel.com/docs/4.0/kiosk) states that a dynamic list can be used in place of the $developers array, but there is no hint on where to place this:

`Spark::developers($developers);`

I can easily retrieve a specific team's emails to pass as the parameter, but I can't figure out the placement! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

The Laravel documentation makes it sound like the `booted()` method in the App\Providers\SparkServiceProvider is reserved for registration commands, but this ended up being the place to put my database-filled command of `Spark::developers($developers);`.